# Run an animation before I submit a form (and make sure it completes)

Tags: jquery, forms

So I have a little form (`#edit_form`) with elements from a database. The checked elements are assigned the class `.selected`, and when the user submits the form, I want them to slide up before the form is actually submitted and the page reloads. I have tried this:

```
$("#edit_form").submit(function(){
    $('.selected').slideUp(800,function(){
        $("#edit_form").submit();
    });
});
```

The problem is that the form just submits, and doesn't wait until the animation is complete. I have also tried this:

```
$("#edit_form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.selected').slideUp(800,function(){
        $("#edit_form").submit();
    });
});
```

This makes the animation fire, but the form is never submitted. Here is another one I tried (the submit button has an id of `#formsubmit`):

```
$("#formsubmit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.selected').slideUp(800,function(){
        $("#edit_form").submit();
    });
});
```

I have tried that with and without the `preventDefault()`, and they both do the same as if I am trying to intercept the form submit action. Anybody have any other ideas?

Comment: `.click()(function(e){` is not valid Javascript. Is that a typo in the code you provided in your question?

Comment: yes, same goes for the submit()(function(e)... should be .submit(function(e){..}); | the second version should work

Comment: Dang, I retyped it wrong. I did have it typed correctly originally though, nice catch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second example is close, however the javascript enters an infinite loop. Do you see it?

When the submit event is handled you call `preventDefault`. Thus, when you submit it programmatically (`$("#edit_form").submit();`) the submit event is just called again, and you prevent it again, and so on.

To solve this, unbind the submit event before programmatically submitting the form:

```
$("#edit_form").unbind("submit").submit();
```

Full code:

```
$("#edit_form").submit(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.selected').slideUp(800,function()
    {
        $("#edit_form").unbind("submit").submit();
    });
});
```

**Edit:** I was wrong. Fixed code.

Comment: Do you mean I should use `get()` on the event handler, or on the submit action? tried them both, with essentially the same results as before: If I use it on the event handler, the form get submitted and the animation is never fired. If I use it on the submit action, the animation fires but the form is never submitted.

Comment: @Nick `.get()` get's the DOM element of a jQuery object. I'll edit the answer to add some clarity to what I mean.

Comment: @Nick, sorry, my mistake. Fixed the code, it should be working now.

Comment: Hey, I have tried this and it still isn't working.  It is still just not submitting the form.  I am starting to wonder if it is a problem somewhere else in my code, but I really don't think so. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @Nick, it works in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JBrCC/), so it might be somewhere else in your code.