# How to stop a form from submitting until an animation is complete

Tags: jquery, forms, animation, submit, preventdefault

I am trying to run an animation on a form after the user has clicked the submit button and before it submits. I did find solutions here on stackoverflow and on other sites but they either resulted in the form submitting before the animation could run, or the animation would run but the form would not submit.  It's just for my sister's wedding website so my job isn't in jeopardy but it would be nice to make her site special.

note that the **developer console returns no errors.**

This is the code we started with: [Executing a form after animation is done JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052426/executing-a-form-after-animation-is-done-jquery). It is an accepted answer so i'm assuming it worked for somebody, but I don't understand how the preventDefault function is supposed to work when nothing is passing the  event to it. I also tried this one: [Run an animation before I submit a form (and make sure it completes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573385/run-an-animation-before-i-submit-a-form-and-make-sure-it-completes)

Basically the animation is a letter that slides into an envelope which is folded then slides off screen.

Here's the form.

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
    <label>names</label>
    <input type="text" name="names" id="nameInput" placeholder="type here" />
    <label>food allergies</label>
    <input type="text" name="allergies" placeholder="type here" />
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send Email">
</form>
```

and here's the jQuery.  **updated with @Roamer-1888's code**

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();

var imgPosition = ($('.mobile_background').width() - windowWidth) / 2;
var centreTriangle = (windowWidth / 2) - 35;

function sendMail(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = e.target;

    var setTop = function () {
        return $('.letter').animate({top: 2}, 1000).promise();
    }
    var openEnvelope = function () {
        return $('.envelope_fold.top_up').slideUp().promise();
    }
    var insertContents = function () {
        return $('input').css('display', 'none');
        // you probably need also to do something here to prevent the inputs from showing again when the envelope is animated off screen. eg append the inputs to the envelope element. 
    }
    var closeEnvelope = function () {
        return        $('.envelope_fold.shaddow').add('.envelope_fold.top_down').slideDown(300).promise();
    }
    var sealEnvelope = function () {
        return $('#seal').css('display', 'block');
    }
    var exitStageRight = function () {
        return $('#envelope').animate({left: 3000}).promise();
    }
    var send = function () {
        form.submit();
    }

    if ($('#nameInput').val() == "") {
        alert('Please tell us your name');
    } else {
        $.when() //resolved promise to get the chain started
            .then(setTop)
            .then(openEnvelope)
            .then(insertContents)
            .then(closeEnvelope)
            .then(sealEnvelope)
            .then(exitStageRight)
            .then(send);
    }
}


function showMenu() {
    $('.navButton').css({
        right: '111px'
    });
    $('#menu').css({
        left: 0
    }, 300);
}

function hideMenu() {
    $('.navButton').css({
        right: '10px'
    }); 
    $('#menu').css({
        left: '100%'
    }, 300);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    // styles
    $('#intro').css({
        'height': $(window).height()
    });

    $('.mobile_background').css({
        'right': -imgPosition
    });

    $('.triangle').css({
        'margin-left': centreTriangle
    });

    // countdown clock
    $('#count').countdown('2015/01/17 13:30:00', function(event) {
       $(this).html(event.strftime('<h3>%D<span>d</span> %H<span>h</span> %M<span>m</span</h3>'));
    });

    // form submit verification removal
    $('.success a').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });

    // Navigation
    $('.navButton').on('click', function(){
        showMenu();
    });

    $('body > div, #menu a').on('click', hideMenu);


    if (windowWidth > 1025) {
        $('nav').mouseenter(function(){
            showMenu();
        });
        $('nav').mouseleave(function(){
            hideMenu();
        });     
    }

    if (windowWidth <= 400) {
        $('.navButton').on('click', function(){
            showMenu();
            $('body > div').css({
                right: '101px'
            });
        });

        $('body > div + div, #menu a').on('click', function(){
            hideMenu();
            $('body > div').css({
                right: 0
            });
        });
    }

    // fire form animation
    $("form:eq(0)").on('submit', sendMail);
});
```

Also I want the first step of the animation to make the inputs go behind the front of the envelope but it prevents all of the functions running after that from working. I have to have them in front of the envelope at first otherwise users wouldn't be able to enter text. So if anyone can figure that out that would also be great.

scroll to the bottom of this site to see the form: http://celinaanddavid.ca

Thanks for the help.

Comment: There is a JavaScript error on your site, when you hit the send button, try to run the function outside the form context (e.g. onload) to debug.

Comment: With that `submit` event handler commented your next line of code is obviously now invalid (as `e` is no longer defined for `e.preventDefault();`)! Best fix that first.

Comment: [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) applies only to positioned elements. If either the input elements or the envelope are not positioned, then z-index will have no effect.

Comment: okay, I have made those changes.  The animation is working now but the form still submits before the animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For serial animations like this, you can avoid that horrible "pyramid of doom" (deep nested callbacks) by exploiting jQuery's promises and writing a nice friendly `.then()` chain.

And to make the code even more readable, it is also a good idea to write each animation step as a named function.

You will end up with something like this :

```
function sendMail(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = e.target;

    var setTop = function () {
        return $('.letter').animate({top: 2}, 1000).promise();
    }
    var openEnvelope = function () {
        return $('.envelope_fold.top_up').slideUp().promise();
    }
    var insertContents = function () {
        return $(form).find('input').css('z-index', 0);
        // you probably need also to do something here to prevent the inputs from showing again when the envelope is animated off screen. eg append the inputs to the envelope element. 
    }
    var closeEnvelope = function () {
        return $('.envelope_fold.shaddow').add('.envelope_fold.top_down').slideDown(300).promise();
    }
    var sealEnvelope = function () {
        return $('#seal').css('display', 'block');
    }
    var exitStageRight = function () {
        return $('#envelope').animate({left: 3000}).promise();
    }
    var send = function () {
        form.submit();
    }

    if ($('#nameInput').val() == "") {
        alert('Please tell us your name');
    } else {
        $.when() //resolved promise to get the chain started
            .then(setTop)
            .then(openEnvelope)
            .then(insertContents)
            .then(closeEnvelope)
            .then(sealEnvelope)
            .then(exitStageRight)
            .then(send);
    }
}
```

Now all you need to do is attach `sendMail` as your form's sumbit handler, eg :

```
$("form:eq(0)").on('submit', sendMail);
```

Comment: Thanks @Roamer-1888, that code is much nicer.  Unfortunately it isn't working though.  After clicking the submit button the animation is carried out but the form doesn't submit.  it returns the errors:                                                   TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.preventDefault')
TypeError: HTMLInputElement is not a function (evaluating 'form.submit()')

Comment: Are you attaching `sendMail()` as I said - with `$("form:eq(0)").on('submit', sendMail);` ?

Comment: Yep.  I stripped all other scripts from my .js file and copy-and-pasted your script into it and it still says "HTMLInputElement is not a function (evaluating 'form.submit()')" - referring to the line in the send function.  The only changes I made was changing the colon to a comma in the insertContents function and adding empty brackets after the slideUp in the openEnvelope function.  The animation wouldn't run otherwise.  I even tried changing the action to go to nbc.com like in your example and I got the same thing.  So what could be different? is it the form inputs? is it jQuery 1.10.2?

Comment: The corrections you made are cool - my bad in both cases. I don't think the problem will be with the jQuery version or the form inputs. It's more likely to be that the variable `form` somehow refers to some other element - not the form. Can you test that out?

Comment: I output the form variable to the console before the form.submit() line in the send function and it contained the correct element.  I then tried outputting the variable contents before '$("form:eq(0)").on('submit', sendMail);' line and the variable could not be found.  I have updated my post to show the whole document and the changes we have made.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 this is a cool idea. I've never thought to do that before. I would have used jQuery queues. Thanks.

Comment: In addition, you need to pass the event object as data, so that ``e`` is not undefined:

``$("form:eq(0)").on('submit', {}, sendMail);``

Comment: @EliseChant, I find this approach to be syntactically clearer than a custom animation queue, which needs the counter-intuitive `.dequeue()` to keep it going. If needed, `.delay()` can be emulated by writing your own `function delay(x){...}` employing `setTimeout()`, though you would need to call with the slightly awkward syntax `.delay.bind(null,x)`. I'm sure that custom animation queues have other advantages but I can't think what they might be right now.

Comment: And I don't get you point about passing `e` as data. It's passed automatically in my original `$("form:eq(0)").on('submit', sendMail);`. If it wasn't, then [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7f462132/) wouldn't work, *non*?

Comment: Interesting development I did the craziest thing and Googled the "HTMLInputElement is not a function error" and found out that it was the result of my submit input having the name "submit."  I removed the name then the animation followed by form action worked!  The only problem is the input values didn't get passed through the form submit so it basically just refreshed the page.  But good job @Roamer-1888.  I'd vote up your answer but I am of insufficient repute.

Comment: @semicolin88, that's bizarre, well tracked down! Probably something that crept in with HTML5 where the `name` attribute takes on extra significance. I still don't understand why the inputs' values shouldn't get passed - I can only think that the inputs are not between the `<form>...</form>` tags.

Comment: Make sure the form's method (GET/POST) is compatible with what the server expects. Assuming PHP, if in doubt, try `$_REQUEST[...]`.

Comment: It works if I submit the form to a different file, but not if I submit it back to index.php.  I'm think it's something to do with my isset['send'] to determine if the form has been submitted.  But at this point I'm just being picky.  Having a new page for form submit verification isn't a big deal.

Comment: I just made the validation file redirect back to the index file after sending the email and passed a variable to determine whether or not the form had been submitted.  Works like a charm.  Thanks again, @Roamer-1888.